# how to install intel graphics driver for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus

I have two graphics cards:

1. 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics 4000
2. NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M LE.

I tried to install `nvidia-current`, but it seems not compatible.

After I reboot my computer, it does not display anything. Then I go recovery mode and type:

```
lshw -c video
```

it shows the above two graphics cards, but with `*-display UNCLAIMED`. Also, when I try to `echo $DISPLAY`, it shows nothing.

Comment: I think the underlying problem here is the Nvidia Optimus technology (dual-GPU), not Intel Graphics drivers, which should be there out of the box anyway (built in to the kernel). Google "bumblebee", which is the open-source driver for Nvidia Optimus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your nVidia card to work, the simplest way to do this is to install Bumblebee.

Just search in the Software Center for Bumblebee and install "NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux". Or if you want you can install it manually by this guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

There's also a guide on how to use it.
Hope it's that what you want.
Good luck.